# Autocite near footnotes in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm typesetting a document with references using biblatex. I'm switching back and forth between the authoryear and numeric superscript styles, and the `\autocite` command works wonderfully until I have a sentence which has both a citation and a footnote. Eg:

```
This is a referenced sentence\autocite{Author:2011}\footnote{...requiring a footnote.}.
```

In the numeric/superscript style, both the citation and the footnote show up as superscripts, which is confusing. If I were going completely with the numeric superscript method, I'd modify these occurrences to read something like:

```
This is a referenced sentence (Ref \cite{Author:2011})\footnote{...requiring a footnote.}.
```

But this will end up with the odd (Ref Author,2011) text when using authoryear. Is there some way to manage these occurrences automatically so that I can continue using both of these citation formats from the same document?

Comment: `\autocite` scans ahead one character to move punctuation around. Conceivably you could have `\autocite` look ahead to handle `\footnote`, but this feature would be (at best) nontrivial to implement. Do you use postnotes with `\autocite` under `authoryear`? For you proposed output under `numeric`, how would you distinguish between citation superscripts and footnote marks?

Comment: in this case, I'd change it from ^{131}^1 to (ref 131)^1, where 1 is the footnote and 131 is the reference -- that is, I'd use normal text (`\cite` rather than `\supercite`) for references in this case, which is standard in some journals in my field. Since I've heard no answer, I'll probably have to decide if it's worth putting together a command of my own...

Comment: Would all citation superscripts change from ^x to (ref x)? If not, what about the case: "First sentence (ref 131).^1 Second sentence.^1"? How would one know whether the second superscript refers to the citation or the footnote? A more comprehensive example of what you're wanting to achieve might help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `biblatex` version 1.6 produce the correct behavior:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author="John Smith",
title="TITLE",
year="2009",
publisher="PUP",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
This is a referenced sentence\autocite{test}\footnote{...requiring a footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Noah mentioned a "numeric superscript" style. In other words (I think) `style=numeric,autocite=superscript`. You'll get the defect he's referring to by using those options. It seems he alternates between these and just `style=authoryear`.

Comment: @Audrey: Now we have the verification that a minimal example is very important ;-). I also get another output with `authoryear` as described by the OP

Comment: Yeah. He wants to be able to switch between the two styles, hence the use of the "style-independent" command `\autocite`. This is an interesting problem, but the desired output he's wanting (as I understand it) results in ambiguity between footnote marks and citations. Hopefully he'll respond with some more details and we can work out a solution. I'd leave your answer as a placeholder for now.

Comment: @Audrey: In this case it is only a placeholder :-(. We will wait.

Comment: hrm, thanks for taking another look at this; I just handed in a draft of my thesis to my committee but have the defense upcoming so I won't have a chance to look at this again until I work on formatting the final library version :)